# Can I add more properties to a control?

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik

I have a problem in my application: I have to handle many **Telerik RadComboBox**, the detail is that each belongs to a certain concept; I used the Teg property to add the Ids of the concepts to which it belongs. The problem arises when I go around the list of **RadComboBox**, have to do Split to separate Ids does not work much because performance is severely affected.
Is there any way to add these new properties to **RadComboBox**?

I help a lot to do something like this:

```
RadComboBox combo = new RadComboBox();
combo.MyIdX = 1;
combo.MyIdY = 2;
combo.MyIdZ = 3;
```

I tried to do this but does not work:

```
public partial class RadComboBox
{
    public int MyIdX { get; set; }
    public int MyIdY { get; set; }
    public int MyIdZ { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can inherit from the RadComboBox

```
public CustomComboBox : RadComboBox
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MyIdxProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("MyIdx", typeof(object), typeof(CustomComboBox), null);
    public object MyIdx
    {
        get
        {
            return GetValue(MyIdxProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(MyIdxProperty, value);
        }
    }
    //etc. etc.
}
```

Then use your new control instead of RadComboBox

```
<local:CustomComboBox MyIdx="1" />
```

Comment: `MyIdx` should be a DependencyProperty in order for this sample to work.

Comment: Good call on the dependency property change.  Thanks for adding the code, @kill4silence.